# Verifying the access token in dropbox?

Tags: python, oauth, python-2.7, dropbox

For this program I'm making in python, I am using dropbox to store some files .
and after following the tutorial on this site:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#python
and It was generally easy to understand all of it , but I have no how how I would actually check if a user clicked allow on the page that dropbox brings up . 
I tried making a loop that will keep running until the token is valid , but that seems kind of stupid  and if the user wanted to click deny then the loop would never end.
I saw something on the page about Oauth_callback but I'm new to programming so I have no idea how to take the information giving when the user is redirected , and match it to the user .

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation at the link you've provided, the user is supposed to go to the page press *allow* and then tell your application that the request has been allowed. You shouldn't worry about checking if it has already been allowed, and leave that responsibility to the used. Of course the call to `sess.obtain_access_token` will fail if allow hasn't been pressed, but in that case just restart the authorisation process until the user does allow in the page before continuing.